# Puppet deleting shell scripts in /root of server?

Tags: shell, puppet

How can I run my own shell scripts without having to worry about puppet deleting these or having to call these at runtime?

Comment: puppet shouldn't delete anything by its own.. In your puppet-root area, e.g. /etc/puppet, search for the name of your script or look for any command that does a cleaning operation in /root area, e.g. "Tidy"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no module which takes care of */root* then puppet never delete or run your script. So if your script gets deleted search for the proper module and deactive it for your host.